# How to remove the "Server" tag from the header of my server response

Tags: node.js, laravel, security, server, middleware

I set up a Laravel and an Express Node and I want to eliminate the "Server" label that the server returns in the response.

I made a middleware to remove said label but I still can't remove it.

Does anyone know how I can activate it?

[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXGUx.png)

PHP: The header_remove does not work, nor does modifying it for an empty one.

```
class removeServerHeader
{
    /**
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->remove('X-OpenSSL-Version');
        $response->headers->remove('x-powered-by');
        $response->headers->remove('Server');
        $response->header('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Node: res.removeHeader('Server'); doses not work.

```
const removeServerHeader = (req, res, next) => {
  res.removeHeader('Server');
  next();
};
```

Comment: Take a look here since it seams you use nginx: https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the header on nginx or apache. [server_tokens off](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens);

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf;

server_tokens off;
```

do you have access to the configuration?

Comment: Yes, i have access. and server tokens off
```server {
  server_tokens off;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/html/app/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  location / {...}
  location ~ \.php$ {...}
}```

Comment: To disable on the express side, try  `const express = require('express');
const app = express();
 app.disable('x-powered-by')`

Comment: And also if you want to protect your application better, look towards [helmetjs](https://helmetjs.github.io/)